# ObjectStorageAsyc doesnt wait for completion

Tags: java, asynchronous, helidon

when I run below code from Helidon MP Main Program this works fine for all simultaneous uploads but 
when I run code from Test I need to wait some thing like threadSleep(time) for some time before serverstops for all files to get uploaded other wise it only uploads few files. Can you please help

```
ObjectStorageAsync client = new ObjectStorageAsyncClient(provider).getClient();
    client.putObject(putObjectRequest, putObjectHandler);
    PutObjectResponse response = putObjectHandler.waitForCompletion();
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to concern only the Oracle Object Storage APIs, and not anything related to Helidon.

I also notice that [`putObject`'s](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/objectstorage/ObjectStorageAsync.html#putObject-com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.requests.PutObjectRequest-com.oracle.bmc.responses.AsyncHandler-) second argument is an [`AsyncHandler`](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/responses/AsyncHandler.html), which does not seem to have the `waitForCompletion()` method you reference above.

Finally, I note that the [`putObject`](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/objectstorage/ObjectStorageAsync.html#putObject-com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.requests.PutObjectRequest-com.oracle.bmc.responses.AsyncHandler-) method returns a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which you are not using (which is correct, it looks like, from the documentation, if you are supplying an `AsyncHandler`).  In your case, perhaps it might make more sense to supply `null` as the second argument to [`putObject`](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/objectstorage/ObjectStorageAsync.html#putObject-com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.requests.PutObjectRequest-com.oracle.bmc.responses.AsyncHandler-), and call [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) on the returned `Future` instead, which will block until the computation is finished?  (This of course would make the asynchronous nature of what you are doing somewhat irrelevant, but it seems like what you want to do.)

Finally, if you must block until everything is done, then perhaps you don't want to use the asynchronous API at all, and would be more interested in the [synchronous API instead](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/objectstorage/ObjectStorage.html).